# Appname.deploy.cmd - The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, iis, tfs, windows-server

I'm trying to set up automated deployment of my application via TFS using the web deploy package publishing method. I've successfully created the build artifact with the `appname.zip` deploy package in it and an `appname.deploy.cmd` (generated by visual studio) using a build definition.

However, when attempting to deploy it, it fails to run the cmd file with the error "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform". I have no idea why this might be happening or what I might have missed, especially as this is my first time configuring a build/release definition in TFS. Both visual studio & TFS are 2015 and I'm trying to deploy an ASP .NET application.

The release definition steps are:

1- Copy files from $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ to F:\WebDeployPackage (runs ok)

2- Run PowerShell F:\WebDeployPackage\App\drop\AppName\obj\Release\appname.deploy.cmd /Y "-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='AppName'" (Error)

I've checked that the file path is correct & it is present in the same path in the artifacts after the corresponding build. I've also searched for this error but it seems to be very case-specific and I couldn't relate any other answer/google results to my case.

I am not sure if the issue is in my target server or in my release definition or elsewhere, any help appreciated.

Comment: Does your build agent run on Windows machine? Can you try using "Batch Script" task to run the cmd file?

Comment: Hi, yes it does. Thus far it looks like an internal security software that runs in our machines is blocking the execution of the script - it took me a while to notice this but I saw the "blocked message" during an RDP to the server while deploying. I am trying to fix this issue first, if this resolves the problem then this is an environment-specific issue...

Comment: It was an internal problem, with an security software running on the server. Unrelated to the build/release configurations or TFS. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested a similar release and worked as expected. So there is nothing wrong with your script or argument:

[image]

Maybe the issue is related to deployment environment. You need to go the machine that you want to deploy to and run the powershell command manually ob this machine to see whether it works. Also, you may try deploying to another machine to see whether it works.